# Julia on Hydrogen on Atom (Windows 10) Error Message

Tags: windows, path, julia, atom-editor, cson

I get the following popup in red.

```
Failed to load snippets from 'C:\Users\18148.atom\packages\language- 
julia\snippets\language-julia.cson'

C:\Users\18148\.atom\packages\language-julia\snippets\language-julia.cson: 
Duplicate key '.source.julia'
```

Julia on Hydrogen on Atom runs fine. But I don't want to see this message every time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the file `C:\Users\18148.atom\packages\language- 
julia\snippets\language-julia.cson`. Then there at the top you will see two entries starting with `.source.julia`. Remove the line 10 `".source.julia":` and the error should be fixed.

There already is a pull request for `language-julia`. https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/atom-language-julia/pull/147/commits/a5d54accfd8ceabea4b80b192ab9943435bf159c

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. Sorry I am new so I cannot upvote yet. Once I can I will.